# Python list-comprehension too slow

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, for-loop, list-comprehension

I have 231 pdf files and would like to convert each of them to a string format. Subsequently, I will save each of these strings to in a txt file.

I was able to create a code for this (I checked that it works when I ran the code for a smaller number of elements), but python did not finish executing the program even after 10h!

I tried the same code using "for loop", but it is too slower too. Any idea how could I make this code faster?

Here is my code:

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, 
PDFPageInterpreter#process_pdf
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

from io import StringIO

def pdf_to_text(pdfname):

    # PDFMiner boilerplate
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    sio = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, sio, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)

    # Extract text
    fp = open(pdfname, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()

    # Get text from StringIO
    text = sio.getvalue()

    # Cleanup
    device.close()
    sio.close()

    return text

lista2 = [pdf_to_text(k) for k in lista1]
```

Where `lista1` is the list with my 231 pdfs

The pdf files were extract from this [website](http://www.senado.leg.br/publicacoes/anais/asp/IP_AnaisImperio.asp). I selected only the files with the word "Livro" in the name.

Comment: Can you post a zip archive with the PDF files so we can reproduce?

Comment: Where is the profiler output?

Comment: As far as i can see - you can move `PDFMiner boilerplate` from function to `__main__` scope and do cleanup after processing all pdf files

Comment: I do not think the loop or comprehension are taking the bulk of the time. You might want to make your function less silent and log your progress to see what is happening.

Comment: I edited the question to show the site where I took the pdfs. So, now the code can be replicated

Comment: I've opened some random "Livro" file. 179 pages. looks like you are out of memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the files you are processing are quite big (10MB), so the long execution time is expected. There is not much you can do to speed up the execution of your program, apart from more parallelization and being more cautious with memory. That is, you can do the following:

- use multi-threading with `multiprocessing.Pool`
- write each text file to disk separately to free up memory

Here is a full program with these optimizations:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from io import BytesIO

from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams

PDF_DIRECTORY = "pdfs"


def pdf_to_text(pdf_filename):
    # PDFMiner boilerplate
    pdf_resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
    bytes_io = BytesIO()
    device = TextConverter(
        pdf_resource_manager, bytes_io, codec="utf-8", laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(pdf_resource_manager, device)

    # Extract text
    with open(pdf_filename, "rb") as fp:
        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp):
            interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = str(bytes_io.getvalue())

    # Cleanup
    bytes_io.close()
    device.close()

    # Print current filename with some of the parsed text
    print("{} - {}".format(pdf_filename, text[:15].replace("\n", "")))

    return text


def process_pdf_file(pdf_filename):
    text_filename = "{}.txt".format(os.path.splitext(pdf_filename)[0])

    # Write the text file to disk to avoid having to keep
    # it in memory
    with open(text_filename, "w") as text_file:
        text_file.write(pdf_to_text(pdf_filename))


def main():
    pdf_filename_list = []
    for filename in os.listdir(PDF_DIRECTORY):
        if not filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            continue
        pdf_filename_list.append(os.path.join(PDF_DIRECTORY, filename))

    MULTITHREAD = True
    if MULTITHREAD:
        # Use a thread pool to process multiple PDF files at the same time
        pool = Pool(cpu_count())
        pool.map(process_pdf_file, pdf_filename_list)
    else:
        # Version without thread pool
        for pdf_filename in pdf_filename_list:
            process_pdf_file(pdf_filename)


main()
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the great use cases for generators: conserving memory.

Often, all you need to do is iterate over the files, transforming one at a time and streaming the output somewhere else.  Say, for example:

```
for f in files:
   text = pdf_to_text(f)
   output.write(text)
```

-- then you don't want (or need) a list comprehension, in fact you never need to create a list at all.  Instead, consider just iterating over the elements one at a time.  Or create a generator, if that makes more sense.

Keep in mind that the garbage collector cannot release memory if you still have a reference to it.  If you create a list comprehension then all of the elements in it (and items those elements reference) must be preserved in memory all at one time.  Usually you only need this if you plan to access the elements frequently or in a non-linear order.

You should also consider the possibility that processing large files even if you can do `allocate`/`transform`/`deallocate` may still be "too slow" if we're talking about many gigabytes worth being read/written.  In this case the best alternative is often considering using a C extensions that will provide better control over how memory is allocated and used.  Also, `pypy` works in the vast majority of cases and is usually much faster than CPython.